# titanium iOS cannot set a date to datepicker

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am using a datepicker in titanium iOS to read date.
When I am trying to set a value to the date picker t wont work.It is always showing the maxDate.
What is the actual solution for this

```
//my sample code of picker is follows
var picker2 = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type: Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
    selectionIndicator: true,
    minDate: new Date(moment().subtract(120, 'years')),
    maxDate: new Date(moment().subtract(18, 'years')),
    value: new Date(2014,3,12),
    //value: navHistory == 'profilePage' && dateofbirth !=null ? dateofbirth : new Date(moment().subtract(18, 'years')),
    top: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight / 30,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your current solution does not work is because your value is actually a date after your maxDate (hence it will set the value to maxDate). You need to use a date within minDate and maxDate as value for it to work.

For example:

```js
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type: Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
    selectionIndicator: true,
    minDate: new Date(moment().subtract(120, 'years')),
    maxDate: new Date(moment().subtract(18, 'years')),
    value: new Date(1990,3,12)
});
```